# How to navigate the REST endpoints and retrieve Field information programatically

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, rest, arcgis-rest-api

I'm adding a Dynamic Map Service to an ArcGIS Server JavaScript API map, and I need to get hold of each component layer and its fields, so I can run a query.

See the sample ArcGIS Server services directory at http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/HomelandSecurity/operations/MapServer

If you open this URL in a browser you can see the list of available **layers** (0,1,2) and each layer's **fields**.

How can I retrieve the list of fields programatically, within a JavaScript function? The code snippet below shows how to retrieve the layer endpoints, but I can't see how to get to the fields.

(One option is to add the layers as Feature Layers, but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible).

```
var url = "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/HomelandSecurity/operations/MapServer/";
var dynLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(url);
map.addLayer(dynLayer);

dojo.connect(dynLayer, "onLoad", function() {
   var infos = dynLayer.layerInfos;
   for (var i = 0; i <= infos.length - 1; i++) {
       var layerId = infos[i].id;
       var restEndPoint = url + layerId;
       //restEndPoint is the layer's URL - how can I retrieve its fields?
   }
});
```

Thanks,
Steve (cross-posted to the [ArcGIS Server forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/37332-How-to-retrieve-the-Fields-available-in-a-Dynamic-map-s-sub-layers))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use esri.request() to hit each layer's REST endpoint to get info about fields. Here's a simple example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.require("esri.map");
      // var service_url = 'http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hurricanes/NOAA_Tracks_1851_2007/MapServer/layers';
      var service_url = 'http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Fire/Sheep/MapServer/layers';

      function init() {
        esri.request({
          url: service_url,
          content: { f: 'json' },
          callbackParamName: 'callback',
          load: processServiceInfo,
          error: errorHandler
        });
      }
      // Runs once
      function processServiceInfo(info) {
        console.log('svc info: ', info);
        dojo.byId('info').innerHTML = '';
        dojo.forEach(info.layers, function(lyr) {

          // Add a new div for each Layer
          var lyr_div = dojo.create('div', { 
            id: 'layer_' + lyr.id,
            innerHTML: '<strong>Layer: ' + lyr.name + '</strong><br />'
          }, dojo.byId('info'));

          dojo.forEach(lyr.fields, function(field) {
            lyr_div.innerHTML += 'Name: ' + field.name + '; Alias: ' + field.alias + '<br />';
          });
        });
      }

      function errorHandler(err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
      }

      dojo.ready(init);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="info">field names and aliases will show up here.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

That code uses v2.0 of the API but the same thing will work at 2.3 or 2.4. I originally posted in the [Esri JS API forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/7793-Identify-How-to-show-Alias-filed-instead-of-Field-Name?p=24158&viewfull=1#post24158).

**Edit:**  Updated to handle all layers in a service. The code also now uses version 2.4 of the API.

Comment: +1 Looks good.  Since user has 3 layers though, maybe having init call a FieldsInit function for each layer might be more useful.

Comment: esri.request is the way to go, but instead of querying individual layers, just query them all at once by using http://..../MapServer/layers?f=json as the URL.

Comment: Between you all, I think we have a great answer :) @Derek can you edit the code to handle all layers as per Sasa's suggestion, and I'll mark it as accepted? Thanks everyone

Comment: There ya go Steve...updated my code sample to provide info for all layers in a map service.

Comment: Thanks. I'm loading the JSON result into a global variable which I can then access at any time, to determine the layers and fields available in the map. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I may have the wrong end of the stick here, but don't you just perform a query on the layer in question and get the results back as a resultset?  If you ask for it in json, you can parse the results?

So for this:

http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/1/query?where=STATE_NAME%3D%27Florida%27&f=json

The return is:

{"displayFieldName":"STATE_NAME","fieldAliases":{"STATE_NAME":"STATE_NAME"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon","spatialReference":{"wkid":4326},"fields":[{"name":"STATE_NAME","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"STATE_NAME","length":25}],"features":[{"attributes":{"STATE_NAME":"Florida"},"geometry":{"rings":[[[-80.785662408630856,28.785194039580265],  ...   [-80.5878197219821,24.956376399079556],[-80.249453677873134,25.354937642313288]]]}}]}

*(I have removed most of the geometry to make it easier reading)*

Comment: how did you know to query layer 1, and that there was a field called STATE_NAME? That's what I'm trying to work out on-the-fly (ie, I need this to work for ANY rest endpoint at run-time, not one that I know beforehand). Thanks

Comment: well the simplest answer would be to count the layers in the map service, and each other map service, and loop through them requesting the data.  A query can just be a null one, so you bring everything back.  You can then loop through the response listing the data.

Comment: so in my example above, I'd set a QueryTask based on each restEndPoint, and build a query which didn't return geometry - good idea. I'll give it a try - thanks!

Comment: That's how I'd approach it

Comment: Try this: Url to layer URL/YOURLAYERNAME/MapServer/layers?f=json - This should return a json depiction of all your layers and their fields or URL/YOURLAYERNAME/MapServer/1?f=json indicating the layer number you want

Comment: It also works like thus: URL/YOURLAYERNAME/MapServer/?f=json for all layers

Comment: I just wonder whether this will be a slow process - having to wait until each query has finished? I'll also look into polling the REST API directly to see if it's any faster

Comment: If you query all layers, it's quick and you get all the info in one block